# how to add EntryCell to Xamarin.Forms Content

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am new on **Xamarin.Forms** and I am trying to use `EntryCell`

```
AccountId = new EntryCell {Label="Account Id", Text = CustomersPage.staticCustomer.AccountId};
```

When I am trying to add `EntryCell` to content page:

```
Content = new StackLayout {
    Children = {
        AccountId              
    }
};
```

I get the following error:

> The best overloaded Add method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.Add(Xamarin.Forms.View)'
>   for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Why can't I add `EntryCell` directly just like `Entry`?

Comment: I don't think EntryCell can be inserted into a StackLayout directly.  I believe it belongs to a TableView.  Please refer to the documentation here, https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.EntryCell/ .

Comment: @Bearcat9425 thanks ... actually just now i do the same , i used TableView but i want to know why ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actullay I was searching away to use Label And Text on the same time So
As @Arkadiusz said

I used TableView like that :

```
  TableView tb = new TableView(); 
  tb.Root = new TableRoot() { new TableSection("Info") { AccountId }};        
  Content = new StackLayout { Children={ tb, ProcessToCheckOut } }
```

or
I need to user Entry && Label  instead of EntryCell And Change stackLayout orientation To Horizontal

Answer (score 1):

`EntryCell` doesn't derive from `View`, therefore you cannot add it as a child to `StackLayout` children collection.

`EntryCell` is intented to use with `ListView` (also with `TableView`) control, generally due to performance reasons. `EntryCell` derives from `Cell` which provides description of a visual element rather than is a visual element.

On the other side `Entry` derives from `View`, thus you can add it to `StackLayout`.

Comment: @ArkaduisZ K...thanks . but i wan to use EntryCell because i need to use label and text on the same time .. i used a TableView like that .. could you please use my code in your answer       TableView tb = new TableView();
               tb.Root = new TableRoot() {
             new TableSection("Tcetra Info") {
          AccountId         
              }};
              
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children={
    tb,
                ProcessToCheckOut
    }
            };

Comment: You can always edit your question and add additional question/explanation :)

Comment: Why couldn't you create a label and an Entry?  if you need them side by side you could set your stackLayout orientation options to Horizontal.

Comment: Exactly as @Bearcat9425 wrote, you can layout your UI elements as you want